# multipart index in zoo timeseries

Tags: r, zoo

I am working with trade dataset with thousands of rows. Every record has a unique key based on a symbol and date. Trade records for a given symbol are irregular, hence using zoo will be natural choice. I need to use lag  and merge to create a new dataset. However, I don't know how to setup multi-column index in zoo in order to use lag function. Below is a sample dataset and intended output.

```
df = data.frame(
    dt = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06",
                   "2015-01-01", "2015-01-02")),
    id = c("i1", "i1", "i1", "i2", "i2"),
    v1 = c(110, 115, 119, 212, 213),
    v2 = c(100, 170, 180, 202, 210),
    v3 = c(11, 13, 16, 22, 24)
)
df$id = as.character(df$id)
```

And the output should be

```
2015-01-01, i1, 110, 100, 11, 2015-01-05, i1, 115, 170, 13 
2015-01-05, i1, 115, 170, 13, 2015-01-06, i1, 119, 180, 16 
2015-01-06, i1, 119, 180, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
2015-01-01, i2, 212, 202, 22, 2015-01-02, i2, 213, 210, 24 
2015-01-02, i2, 213, 210, 24, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
```

In SO, there are number of posts accomplishing "grouped" lag operations but for a single column only. I am looking for merging complete row, regardless of number of columns.

Update to this question...

Following is one possible way to solve the "grouped" lag operation based on zoo.

```
doProcessing = function(df){
  icolnames = colnames(df)
  tt = zoo(df, df$dt)
  tt1 = merge(tt, lag(tt, 1))
  colnames(tt1) = c(icolnames, paste0("lag_", icolnames))
  data.frame(tt1, stringsAsFactors=F)
}
fin_df = do.call(rbind, with(df, by(df, list(id), doProcessing, simplify=F)))
```

This final output frame has every field as factor. How do I get the output structure right as per input data frame?

---

Based on @Grothendieck's idea of lapply, a possible solution to the above problem is given below.

```
doProcessing = function(df){
  icolnames = colnames(df)
  tt = zoo(df, df$dt)
  tt1 = merge(tt, lag(tt, 1))
  colnames(tt1) = c(icolnames, paste0("lag_", icolnames))
  data.frame(tt1, stringsAsFactors=F)
}

fin_df = do.call(rbind, with(df, by(df, list(id), doProcessing, simplify=F)))
```

Still need some help, some how resultant data frame has every column as factors. How do I get original structure back?

original data frame structure

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ dt: Date, format: "2015-01-05" "2015-01-01" ...
 $ id: chr  "i1" "i1" "i1" "i2" ...
 $ v1: num  115 110 119 212 213
 $ v2: num  170 100 180 202 210
 $ v3: num  13 11 16 22 24
```

resultant data frame looks like

```
> str(fin_df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ dt    : Factor w/ 4 levels "2015-01-01","2015-01-05",..: 1 2 3 1 4
 $ id    : Factor w/ 2 levels "i1","i2": 1 1 1 2 2
 $ v1    : Factor w/ 5 levels "110","115","119",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ v2    : Factor w/ 5 levels "100","170","180",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ v3    : Factor w/ 5 levels "11","13","16",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ lag_dt: Factor w/ 3 levels "2015-01-05","2015-01-06",..: 1 2 NA 3 NA
 $ lag_id: Factor w/ 2 levels "i1","i2": 1 1 NA 2 NA
 $ lag_v1: Factor w/ 3 levels "115","119","213": 1 2 NA 3 NA
 $ lag_v2: Factor w/ 3 levels "170","180","210": 1 2 NA 3 NA
 $ lag_v3: Factor w/ 3 levels "13","16","24": 1 2 NA 3 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

**zoo** zoo objects are time series so normally the way this is done so that the result is a time series is to use wide form:

```
read.zoo(df, split = 2) # zoo object created by splitting on column 2
```

giving:

```
           v1.i1 v2.i1 v3.i1 v1.i2 v2.i2 v3.i2
2015-01-01   110   100    11   212   202    22
2015-01-02    NA    NA    NA   213   210    24
2015-01-05   115   170    13    NA    NA    NA
2015-01-06   119   180    16    NA    NA    NA
```

**list** or simply split the data frame into a list of zoo objects

```
L <- lapply(split(df[-2], df$id), read.zoo)
```

giving:

```
> L
$i1
            v1  v2 v3
2015-01-01 110 100 11
2015-01-05 115 170 13
2015-01-06 119 180 16

$i2
            v1  v2 v3
2015-01-01 212 202 22
2015-01-02 213 210 24
```

**melt** Using the reshape2 package we could create long form:

```
m <- melt(df, id = 1:2)
```

giving:

```
> m
           dt id variable value
1  2015-01-01 i1       v1   110
2  2015-01-05 i1       v1   115
3  2015-01-06 i1       v1   119
4  2015-01-01 i2       v1   212
5  2015-01-02 i2       v1   213
6  2015-01-01 i1       v2   100
7  2015-01-05 i1       v2   170
8  2015-01-06 i1       v2   180
9  2015-01-01 i2       v2   202
10 2015-01-02 i2       v2   210
11 2015-01-01 i1       v3    11
12 2015-01-05 i1       v3    13
13 2015-01-06 i1       v3    16
14 2015-01-01 i2       v3    22
15 2015-01-02 i2       v3    24
```

In this form it's easy to get various slices.  For example,

```
> subset(m, dt == "2015-01-01")
           dt id variable value
1  2015-01-01 i1       v1   110
4  2015-01-01 i2       v1   212
6  2015-01-01 i1       v2   100
9  2015-01-01 i2       v2   202
11 2015-01-01 i1       v3    11
14 2015-01-01 i2       v3    22
```

**3d array** Another possibility is to represent it as a three dimensional array.  `m` is from `melt` solution above.  We could permute the components of the second argument to get variations:

```
a <- acast(m, ... ~ id ~ dt)

giving:

, , 2015-01-01

    i1  i2
v1 110 212
v2 100 202
v3  11  22

, , 2015-01-02

   i1  i2
v1 NA 213
v2 NA 210
v3 NA  24

, , 2015-01-05

    i1 i2
v1 115 NA
v2 170 NA
v3  13 NA

, , 2015-01-06

    i1 i2
v1 119 NA
v2 180 NA
v3  16 NA
```

Various slices are easy to get: `a[1,,]`, `a[,1,]`, `a[,,1]` .

**Updates** Have added to solution and rearranged and improved some solutions.

Comment: @Grothendieck, output needs to concatenate successive rows of same symbol. read.zoo output is concatenating i1 data with i2 for the same date. This is not the intended output.

Comment: You can't have what you are asking for and still have it as a usable zoo object but I have added a couple of more approaches just in case.

Comment: @Grothendieck, your last suggested approach looks more natural as a starting point, I can apply lag on individual id, the data set has hundreds of symbols and the final result has to have the symbols back. Let me do some work about how to get this done. I will post my findings. Thanks

Comment: Have improved array solution using `acast` from reshape2 package and rearranged presentation.

Comment: @Grothendieck, I got the problem worked out using zoo only, but ran into some str issues. Can you please help?

Comment: Regarding the update to the question which was posted as an answer this gives a list of zoo objects and their lags: `lapply(L, lag, 0:-1)` where `L` is from the answer above.

Comment: Also regarding the question posted as an answer perhaps using data.table would help: `library(data.table); nms <- names(df)[-(1:2)]; dt <- data.table(df); dt[, paste(nms, "lag", sep = ".") := shift(.SD), .SDcols = nms, by = "id"]`